# Can't change current resolution (NVIDIA)

Tags: display-resolution

I've just installed Ubuntu on my computer. NOTICE: I have Windows 10 installed on it too!

I tried to switch to 1440x900 resolution but it isn't working. It is not displaying my resolution. And yeah I looked up a bit on forums for solution but it is really confusing. I'm new to Linux systems and I don't know should I do.

I had this problem in Windows 10 too. Solved it by updating drivers and using NVIDIA CONTROL PANEL to set custom resolution.

I know that there are many topics on this but none of them explains what is what.

Also, what do I need to provide? Some outputs or whatsover? I'm using VGA cable.

Thanks.

```
lspci 

Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 10)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (32 bit).

I'm using 'DVI-I-0' for the connection (although my cable is VGA). So I'm using alternative drivers. This is a image displaying it https://i.stack.imgur.com/afp8w.jpg

Nothing seems to help, i've tried reinstalling drivers, but nothing. Any solution?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify what version of Ubuntu you are using, and whether you are using Wayland or Xorg (17.10 defaults to Wayland). If you can use DVI instead of VGA for the connection, I would also recommend it.

Comment: Also please specify in your [edit] what version of the NVidia graphics driver you're trying to use.

Comment: I've added the info, mind taking a look?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the latest Linux kernel installed (5.4.2) and Nvidia driver 440 doesn't work well with it, I had to downgrade to kernel 5.0. Bleeding edge on Linux is a mistake.

Card GTX 1060, Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nvidia Settings, after installing the driver, to set the preferred resolution in Ubuntu, as shown in the pictures below.

[image: Display config]

[image: Resolution set]

Comment: I installed NVIDIA X Setting server but I don't have that menu You do. I installed it from Ubuntu Software. EDIT 1: I'm trying to install driver now but I can't find it. I've downloaded a .run application and I can't open it, actually I do with sublime text editor.

Comment: What menu do you have? You can add a screenshot to the question to show us.

Comment: This only, https://imgur.com/a/dz9sP

Comment: That means the Nvidia driver is not in use. Are there other GPUs? You can check with `lspci`, might want to add its output to the question.

Comment: Looks ok, Geforce 9500GT is the only GPU. Have you rebooted after installing the driver? What version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: Well I could't install it at all. I'm using 16.04 LTS. By the way while attempting to fix this I somehow managed to set my resolution to lowest after the restart (lol). I put many things on the terminal though. So where should I download drivers from and which one?

Comment: Generally, you should use the Additional Drivers utility in Ubuntu, which will download and install the driver you select, 340.xxx for Geforce 9000. You should add what's been tried to the original question.

Comment: Okay so I managed to get same menu you do. But there is one tiny problem. WHen I change everything I can't click on Apply because I can't see it (My screen resol. is 600x800 at the moment) Is there any shortcut?

Comment: Okay so I changed it and I can see the apply button but when I try to change viewportout to 144x900+0+0 it changes itself to 600x800+0+0. What now lol?

Comment: You could try the Detect Displays to auto-probe for optimal settings. Make sure to remove a previously installed nvidia driver, however you've tried it. In the end, if nothing works, you might opt for a fresh start. After all, Ubuntu is easy to reinstall.

Comment: Can you take a look at my last reply?

Comment: Ok, are you sure 144x900 is right? Shouldn't it be 1440x900?

Comment: Well first and third option are 1440x900 but middle one (viewportout) is 600x800+0+0. I tried changing it to 1440x900 but it keeps reverting to 600x800+0+0.